# How to use Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient<> with client certificate?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, client-certificates

**Context**

I have a tested working Web API service which is configured to client certificate authentication. Now I would like to call it and provide a client certificate. I would like to use `Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient<>` because I generated my typed client classes by using Visual Studio 2015 "Add"/"REST Api client..."

NOTE: I *must* load my X 509 client certificate from file or other stream, because the client will run on a PaaS environment, so I will have no access to any OS provided certificate store.

```
X509Certificate certificate = new X509Certificate(path, password);
```

**Question**

For lower abstraction levels I know how to add client certificate to a request:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(host);
request.ClientCertificates.Add (certificate);
```

However when using higher abstraction level class `Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient<>` I can not figure out where to introduce the client certificate into the call pipeline.

**What I've tried so far**

- I've examined the properties of the some related classes, no certificate
  related properties / methods found
- I've examined the `ServiceClientCredentials` abstract class, but only two descendants found: for token based and basic authentication.
- I've tried to find some IoC facility to get the request just before sending: no success.

Comment: Seems the class loading the cert and taking the ServiceClient is: https://github.com/Azure/autorest/blob/master/ClientRuntimes/CSharp/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime/CertificateCredentials.cs

Comment: Many thanks. That was my guess of solution when "I 've examined the ServiceClientCredentials abstract class, but only two descendants found: for token based and basic authentication"  Interestingly despite of the repo you pointed to,  Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime latest nuget package does not contain this class.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way that works for me.
When I imported my REST API client I modified the following method

**Original**

```
protected CLASSNAME(Uri baseUri, HttpClientHandler rootHandler, params DelegatingHandler[] handlers) : this(rootHandler, handlers)
        {
            if (baseUri == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("baseUri");
            }
            this.BaseUri = baseUri;
        }
```

**I changed protected to public**

```
public CLASSNAME(Uri baseUri, HttpClientHandler rootHandler, params DelegatingHandler[] handlers) : this(rootHandler, handlers)
            {
                if (baseUri == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("baseUri");
                }
                this.BaseUri = baseUri;
            }
```

**How to use**

```
var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
var certFile = Path.Combine(@"path\to\your\certificate", "certificate.pfx");
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(certFile,"<PASSWORD>"));

var client = new CLASSNAME(new Uri("URL"), handler);
//Do your methods on client
```

I hope this can help you are someone else who has the same issue.